# PHP Codeigniter: set_value on dropdown menu

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following view but how do I apply `set_value` to it without it defaulting to Please select?

```
<label for="add_fields_type">Type: </label>
<select name="add_fields_type" id="add_fields_type">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="<?php echo set_value('input'); ?>">Input</option>
    <option value="<?php echo set_value('textarea'); ?>">Text Area</option>
    <option value="<?php echo set_value('radiobutton'); ?>">Radio Button</option>
    <option value="<?php echo set_value('checkbox'); ?>">Check Box</option>
</select>
```

**Update:**

**View:**

```
<label for="add_fields_placeholder">Placeholder: </label>
    <select name="add_fields_placeholder" id="add_fields_placeholder">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="<?php echo set_value('yes'<?php echo set_select('add_fields_placeholder','yes', ( !empty($placeholderType) && $placeholderType == "yes" ? TRUE : FALSE ));?>">Yes</option>
        <option value="<?php echo set_value('no' <?php echo set_select('add_fields_placeholder','no', ( !empty($placeholderType) && $placeholderType == "no" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?>">No</option>
    </select>

    <label for="add_fields_placeholderValue">Placeholder Text: </label>
    <input type="text" name="add_fields_placeholderValue" id="add_fields_placeholderValue" value="<?php echo set_value('add_fields_placeholderValue'); ?>">

    <label for="add_fields_type">Type: </label>
<select name="add_fields_type" id="add_fields_type">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="input" <?php echo set_select('add_fields_type','input', ( !empty($fieldType) && $fieldType == "input" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?>>Input</option>
    <option value="textarea" <?php echo set_select('add_fields_type','textarea', ( !empty($fieldType) && $fieldType == "textarea" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?>>Text Area</option>
    <option value="radiobutton" <?php echo set_select('add_fields_type','radiobutton', ( !empty($fieldType) && $fieldType == "radiobutton" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?>>Radio Button</option>
    <option value="checkbox" <?php echo set_select('add_fields_type','checkbox', ( !empty($data) && $data == "checkbox" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?>>Check Box</option>
</select>
```

**Controller:**

```
$data['fieldType'] = $this->input->get('add_fields_type');
$data['placeholderType'] = $this->input->get('add_fields_placeholder');
```

**Line 16:**

```
<option value="<?php echo set_value('yes'<?php echo set_select('add_fields_placeholder','yes', ( !empty($placeholderType) && $placeholderType == "yes" ? TRUE : FALSE ));?>">Yes</option>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should help:

**Controller (test.php)**

```
<?php
    class Setup extends CI_Controller {

        function index() {
            //for the set_select() function
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            //for base_url() function
            $this->load->helper('url');

            $list['data'] = $this->input->get('add_fields_type');

            $this->load->view('test_view.php', $list);
        }
?>
```

**View (test_view.php)**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>test">
    <label for="add_fields_type">Type: </label>
    <select name="add_fields_type" id="add_fields_type">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="input" <?php echo set_select('add_fields_type','input', ( !empty($data) && $data == "input" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?>>Input</option>
        <option value="textarea" <?php echo set_select('add_fields_type','textarea', ( !empty($data) && $data == "textarea" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?>>Text Area</option>
        <option value="radiobutton" <?php echo set_select('add_fields_type','radiobutton', ( !empty($data) && $data == "radiobutton" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?>>Radio Button</option>
        <option value="checkbox" <?php echo set_select('add_fields_type','checkbox', ( !empty($data) && $data == "checkbox" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?>>Check Box</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** The third parameter of the `set_select()` determines whether it should be selected or not

Comment: Thanks,  I am getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?'

Comment: I have given the complete **Controller** and **View** code now. Simply copy paste and try.

Comment: Replace the error line with `<option value="yes" <?php echo set_select('add_fields_placeholder','yes', ( !empty($placeholderType) && $placeholderType == "yes" ? TRUE : FALSE ));?>>Yes</option>`

Answer (score 5):

Sort of what Abid said, you'd simply use set_value() after your form validation.

```
form_dropdown('add_fields_type', $field_types, set_value('field_type'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<option value="<?php echo set_value('textarea'); ?>" <?php echo (set_value('textarea')=='TEXTAREA')?" selected=' selected'":""?>>Text Area</option>
```

Above TEXTAREA is the value you are expected to come on the option

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

See url:-- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

```
$options = array(
                  'small'  => 'Small Shirt',
                  'med'    => 'Medium Shirt',
                  'large'   => 'Large Shirt',
                  'xlarge' => 'Extra Large Shirt',
                );

$shirts_on_sale = array('small', 'large');

echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, 'large');
```

// Would produce:

```
<select name="shirts">
<option value="small">Small Shirt</option>
<option value="med">Medium Shirt</option>
<option value="large" selected="selected">Large Shirt</option>
<option value="xlarge">Extra Large Shirt</option>
</select>

echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, $shirts_on_sale);
```

// Would produce:

```
<select name="shirts" multiple="multiple">
<option value="small" selected="selected">Small Shirt</option>
<option value="med">Medium Shirt</option>
<option value="large" selected="selected">Large Shirt</option>
<option value="xlarge">Extra Large Shirt</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use set_select you need to have a validation rule for the field in question. See my answer to a similar question here:
[CodeIgniter select_value in form_dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445982/codeigniter-select-value-in-form-dropdown/27475117#27475117)

Answer (score 0):

it is much easier to use javascript(tested)

```
<select name="add_fields_type" id="add_fields_type">
 <option value="">Please Select</option>
 <option value="Input">Input</option>
 <option value="Text Area">Text Area</option>
 <option value="Radio Button">Radio Button</option>
 <option value="Check Box">Check Box</option>
</select>


 <script>
    document.getElementById('select_status').value="<?php echo set_value('status'); ?>";
 </script>
```