# PHP form validation using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a simple form and applied validation to using CodeIgniter's `form_validation->set_rules`.

It works fine but the only issue is when I submit the form with one field blank, it shows a message to fill in that field, but the others fields also become blank.

How can I solve this so that when I submit the form with one field blank, it should show a message for that field, and other fields should hold the data entered in it.

Below is the code:

**View page:**

```
<form name='frm1' action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Registrationc/add_user"  id="form1" method="post">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" style="text-transform: capitalize;" autocomplete="off" id="fname" name="fname">
   <h6 style="color:red;"><?php echo form_error('fname');?></h6>

   <input type="text" class="form-control" style="text-transform: capitalize;" autocomplete="off" id="mname" name="mname">
   <h6 style="color:red;"> <?php echo form_error('mname');?></h6>

   <input type="text" class="form-control" style="text-transform: capitalize;" autocomplete="off" id="lname" name="lname">
   <h6 style="color:red;"><?php echo form_error('lname');?></h6>

   <center>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-bricky" id="subbtn" name="submit">
   </center>
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function add_patient() {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'Firstname', 'trim|required|alpha');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mname', 'Middlename', 'trim|required|alpha');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Lastname', 'trim|required|alpha');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->extra3();
    } else {
        $this->load->model('addpatientM');
        $fname1 = $this->input->post('fname');
        $lname1 = $this->input->post('lname');
        $mname1 = $this->input->post('mname');

        $submit = $this->addpatientM->insert_patient($fname1, $lname1, $mname1);
        if ($submit === true) {
            $this->load->library('session');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'successfully added');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('fail', 'Opps there was some error while inserting');
        }
        redirect('Registrationc/extra3');
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to set value inside each tag like : `<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" size="50" />`

Comment: Thank you @saddam its working

Comment: Does it work for dropdown also ?

Comment: yes you can read this post answer `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876604/php-codeigniter-set-value-on-dropdown-menu`

Comment: But i am fetching values from database for dropdown

Comment: <select class="form-control" id="user_type" name="user_type" value="<?php echo set_value('user_type'); ?>">
<option value="">select</option>
<?php if(!empty($getusertype)){
foreach($getusertype as $user_type){?>
<option value="<?php echo $user_type->user_type_id;?>"><?php echo $user_type->user_type;?></option>
 <?php }                                                                                                                    
 }?></select>

Comment: Above is the code for dropdown

Comment: right now i am not able to run this code but you can do one thing i.e  get selected value in session , when you get back to view page after form validation error you can check session value and each data base value for drop down if session matched with then do selected that option tag and after finish this loop of drop down destroy the session.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163630/discussion-between-nisha-and-saddam).

Answer (score 2):

You need to echo `set_value()` into the value-attribute.

<s>First you need to load form - helper:</s>

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

**Update:** Actually if you're using the `form_validation` library and using validation rules for the field in question, then there's no need to load the `form` helper separately for `set_value`.

Then use set_value in your view to set the value:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" style="text-transform: capitalize;" 
autocomplete="off" id="lname" name="lname" value=<?= set_value("lname"); ?>>
```

[Form Helper: Codeigniter documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html)